# Shift all numbers in an array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

Actually I'm solving a challenge in Hackerrank. I'm new to programming. The challenge I'm facing is to display the number of shifts it takes to sort the given integer array. The thing I didnt understand is the way to shift all the numbers into a sorted array. Is there any simple way to do it?

Comment: It depends ENTIRELY on the language, which in your case is...?

Comment: Isn't shifting described in the description of the problem?

Comment: I am using c language.

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you show us that and where you're stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that **temp**, **index** and **count** are integer variables. (temp =0 and count = 0 ). **array** is the array which we want to sort. **n** is the length of the **array**. If current array element's value is lower than earlier elements value, those values will swap. Each time when there is a swap, 1 will add to **count**.

```
  for (int c = 1 ; c <= n - 1; c++) {
    index= c;

    while ( index > 0 && array[index] < array[index-1]) {
      temp          = array[index];
      array[index]   = array[index-1];
      array[index-1] = temp;
      count=count+1;
      index--;
    }
  }
```